# Youtube Embeded Video Play Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I need to load HTML String (which is embeded code of youtube) in `UIWebview`. the video loads perfect but when i click on it, The issue occur Please check below image. It will open option menu when we right click on youtube video on browser.

Can you guys recognize issue?

I think its Youtube issue. But Still I need Confirmation. Because you can take any embeded url this issue occurs.
Thanks in advance.

here is my Simple code for load html string.

```
[webV loadHTMLString:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"300\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/xakmvJ0WPa4\" width=\"300\"></iframe>" baseURL:nil];
```

and when i click on youtube. Please check attached image.[image]

Comment: I'm suddenly getting this today. Wasn't happening yesterday - so is almost certainly a change in things at Youtube's end. I don't know what is causing the issue yet, though - or a workaround.

Comment: @AdrianBigland Yeah. i saw same post on google group.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, maybe it was an issue on YouTube's end.